# Basic date/time manipulation in NHiberate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, date, hql, criteria-api

I'm trying to restrict my *NHibernate* query with some basic **date/time manipulation**. More specifically, I want to execute the following statement (pseudo-SQL):

```
select * from article where created_on + lifespan >= sysdate
```

with:

- `created_on` is mapped to a property of type `DateTime`.
- `lifespan` is mapped to a property of type `TimeSpan`.
- `sysdate` is the current date/time (of the database server or ofthe application host, I don't care)

Is there any built-in way to do that by using the **Criteria-API** or **HQL**?

```
return session
  .CreateCriteria<Article>()
  .Add( ? )
  .List<Article>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the queries are executed by the server, it needs to support the operations you want to do.

If it does, you'd need to inherit the corresponding Dialect and register the corresponding functions in its constructor.

Comment: +1 Very good reusable proposal that emphasizes NHibernate's extensibility. I guess it's as close as possible to what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
create view activearticle as 
    select * from article 
    where created_on + lifespan >= sysdate
```